# Double integral : $\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \frac{x-y}{(x+y)^3}$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

It is asked to calculate

$$\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \frac{x-y}{(x+y)^3}dxdy \; and \; \int_0^1 \int_0^1 \frac{x-y}{(x+y)^3}dydx$$

and find the relation between my answer and Fubini's theorem.

But for the first integral I got $-\frac{1}{2}$ and the second $\frac{1}{2}$. I thought the integrals should gave the same answer, but I couldnt figure out what I was doing wrong.

Can someone give me a help?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If the results are not the same and Fubini theorem states that under some given hypothesis the results are the same, this means that...

Comment: I know that this function is not defined on $(0,0)$, but I thought that it satisfies the Fubini's theorem, doesn't it?

Comment: Pure logic says it cannot. Why did you think etc.?

Comment: I think it is continuous in $[0,1]$x$ [0,1]$

Comment: Continuity is not even a hypothesis of Fubini. And Fubini has **other** hypotheses.

Comment: With regards to expecting the result to be the same in both integrals, what happens if you just rename the variable $y$ as $x$ and  the variable $x$ as $y$ in the second integral and then compare it to the first?

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FubiniTheorem.html

Comment: If the version of Fubini you know requires continuity, "the relation between the answer and Fubini" can only be that this function has no continuous extension to [0,1]^2. Since this conclusion can trivially be obtained directly, I suspect you are in fact supposed to use the true Fubini--with more interesting consequences. (Say, are you sure you have no other reference for Fubini than some WA page? Already [WP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem) is much better.)