# How to find limits of integration in changed coordinates

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, bounds-of-integration

Given integral = $\iint_R \frac{x-y}{(x+y)^3}dxdy$ :$R=[0,1]\times[0,1]$

Let $u = x+y, v= x-y \implies x = \frac{u+v}{2}, y = \frac{u-v}{2}$

Now x limits are from 0 to 1 and y limits are from 0 to 1. I am not able to understand how to find limits of integration in terms of u, v..

Pls enlighten me.

Comment: Some older posts about the same integral: 
[Double integral : $\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \frac{x-y}{(x+y)^3}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/789119),[How to compute $\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1} \frac{x-y}{(x+y)^3} dxdy$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2031203) or [Calculate $\int_0^1\int_0^1\frac{x-y}{(x+y)^3}dydx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1157761).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We need to consider the original domain in x-y plane which is a square $[0,1]\times[0,1]$ and the consider on that plane the lines

- $u = x+y$
- $v= x-y$

[image]

to see that the range for the two new variables is

- $0\le u\le 2$
- $-1\le v\le 1$

but note that in this case the two variables are not independent thus we need to fix the limits of variation for a first variable and the find the range for the second that is for example

- $0\le u\le 1$
- $-u\le v\le u$

and

- $1\le u\le 2$
- $u-2\le v\le 2-u$

Comment: I did not understand 2nd part. I know $0\leq u \leq 1 , -1 \leq v \leq 1$ But in changed coordinates i think it is not rectangle with limits u = [0,2], v = [-1,1]. So can u pls elaborate how did u get limits of u,v in 2nd part. I am not able to get what it represents in changed coordinates.  I recently started multivariable calculus. Kindly elaborate

Comment: @anirudhb As you can see in the figure we can take the variation for $u$ from $0 to 2$ in the domain and at each values for $u$ corresponds a range for $v$ which depends upon $u$. For example for $u=0 \implies v=0$ and for $u=2 \implies v=0$. In general to find the limits we need to divide the range for $u$ in 2 parts. For the for  $0\le u \le 1\implies -u\le v\le u$ and for  $1\le u \le 2\implies u-2\le v \le 2-u$.

Comment: Sir i am lost. When u =0, the line x+y = u =0 passes thru origin.From this how can we say v=0?

Comment: @anirudhb Recall that the original domain is the square and for $u=0$ we are describing a single point of the domain that is the origin $(0,0)$. For $u=1$ we are describing the segment from the vertex $(1,0)$ to $(0,1)$ and so on.

Comment: i did this in this way as u have told. 
u : 0 to 1 i.e , x+y = u  from origin (u =0) till diagonal of square(u=1). In this part take any point in between : (0, u) and (u,0) will be points of x+y=u line. So v = -u to  u. 
Now take the points (u-1,1) and (1, u-1) are limits of line x+y=u wrto square. Here v = u-2 to 2-u. can you tell me is this correct? is there ny other simpler way ?

Comment: for this i have drawn and thought about the end points of line x+y = u byusing geometry. Took a while. Is there any simpler method or it is like this only.